# how to read xaml from assembly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

To navigate to a specific page in the assembly, the typical code looks like:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("pagename.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

I was wondering if there is a way to read the contents of this XAML file or may be
a way to decompile the embedded BAML file from the assembly directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To instantiate the control from your assembly you need to do the following:

```
    Uri uri = new Uri( "/YourApplication;component/YourWindow.xaml", 
                    UriKind.Relative );
    Window window = (Window)Application.LoadComponent(uri);
```

where Window is the top element of this file. If you want the actual XAML you can use **XamlWriter** to give that to you:

```
String xaml = XamlWriter.Save( window );
```